# Ensemble of EPR pairs

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have N pairs of particles, each pair being in one of the four Bell states, and every Bell state is occupied by the same number of pairs (e.g. if two pairs are in the first Bell state there must also be two pairs in every other Bell state).

The density matrix of the first Bell state is $\rho_1$, of the second Bell state is $\rho_2$, of the third is $\rho_3$ and the fourth is $\rho_4$. What is $\rho_{ij}$, the matrix describing the state of a randomly chosen EPR pair?

If I label the states $\beta_{00}$, $\beta_{01}$, $\beta_{10}$, $\beta_{11}$ then I thought the state of all the pairs might look something like 
$|\psi\rangle =N(\beta_{00} + \beta_{01}+\beta_{10}+\beta_{11})$, and if that's right I could calculate $|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|$ but that would be the matrix for the whole system, not a randomly selected pair.

It must be possible to express $\rho_{ij}$ in terms of the density matrices of the individual states, but I'm not sure how to get there!

Comment: If you choose one of the four Bell pairs simply at random, the density matrix is just $\rho = (\rho_1 + \rho_2 + \rho_3 + \rho_4)/4$.

Comment: @knzhou Why is that though? Because if I select a random pair and it's in the state $\beta_{00}$ which had the density matrix $\rho_1$ associated with it, then shouldn't its density matrix also be just $\rho_1$ rather than that sum?

Comment: That's a different question entirely. If you flip a coin, the result is 50% heads and 50% tails. If you flip a coin and it's heads, then the result is 100% heads.

Comment: Similarly the density matrix conditioned on a random choice is what I gave. But if you then find out it was $\rho_1$, then the density matrix is obviously $\rho_1$. It's almost tautological.